# Starting from zero bitstamp api in python

Tags: python

Starting from stage one trying to connect to bitstamp.
I have a funded account and an api key.

I am trying the following:

```
import bitstamp.client

public_client = bitstamp.client.Public()
print(public_client.ticker()['volume'])


trading_client = bitstamp.client.Trading(username='userNameForWeb', key='apiKeyFromBitStamp', secret='myPasswordFromWeb')


print(trading_client.ticker()['volume'])   
print(trading_client.account_balance()['fee'])
```

Yet getting the error:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
        execfile(filename, namespace)
        File "/Users/jasonmellone/Documents/PythonProjects/bitStamp.py", line 18, in <module>
        print(trading_client.account_balance()['fee'])
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bitstamp/client.py", line 197, in account_balance
        return self._post("balance/", return_json=True)
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bitstamp/client.py", line 47, in _post
        return self._request(requests.post, *args, **kwargs)
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bitstamp/client.py", line 80, in _request
        raise BitstampError(error)
        bitstamp.client.BitstampError: Invalid signature
```

I grabbed the code directly from the [github project](https://github.com/kmadac/bitstamp-python-client).

Happy to use other library for python, but looking for input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trading_client = bitstamp.client.Trading(username='userNameForWeb', key='apiKeyFromBitStamp', secret='myPasswordFromWeb')
```

The secret should not be `myPasswordFromWeb`. The error clearly says you have an 'Invalid signature.'. The secret should be the api_secret key that bitstamp shows you only ONE TIME when you generate an API key. Generate a new API key and store the secret key it gives you. Your secret key will be almost (if not equally) as long as your API key. Hope this helps.

Comment: For someone brand new at this 'Invalid Signature' was tough to link directly to the api secret that you see once (possibly prior to fully understanding how it fits into the architecture). I generated a new api key - replaced 'myPasswordFromWeb' with the new api secret and it works perfectly.

Comment: Ya, I understand, BTC API is a entirely new thing, so it can be confusing. Glad it helped :)